# Mysql asks for a default value for an auto incremented primary key field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am facing a strange problem . I'm using `mysqli extension` from php and am calling a stored function in mysql , which inserts some values in a table , i leave the user_id field vacant since it is auto-incremented , however the insert query fails stating i don't have a default value for user_id , which is already an auto-increment field .. I am posting the stored function .

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `ideaforum`.`login_handler` (
login                  ENUM('facebook','twitter','google','local'),
firstname              VARCHAR(40),
middlename             VARCHAR(40),
lastname               VARCHAR(40),
gender                 ENUM('male','female'),
emailid                VARCHAR(50),
remoteid               VARCHAR(70)
)
RETURNS INT

BEGIN
    DECLARE user_exists INT DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000'
    SET user_exists = FALSE;

    SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE email=emailid 
    INTO user_exists;

    IF user_exists = FALSE THEN
        INSERT INTO user
            (login_type,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,remote_id)
        VALUES
            (login,firstname,middlename,lastname,gender,emailid,remoteid);

        INSERT INTO contact
            (contact_type,contact_details)
        VALUES("email",emailid);

        SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE email = emailid INTO user_exists;
        RETURN(user_exists);
    ELSE
        RETURN(user_exists);
    END IF;

END
```

Comment: Show us the "show create table ``user`` ;"

Comment: "query fails stating i don't have a default value for user_id" --- provide the **original** error message

Comment: Gotcha I want to see the layout and constraint on the table you are manipulating... Probably relevant for a constraint error question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably caused by the second insert query. Move it after the `select` and change it to:

```
INSERT INTO contact (
    user_id, contact_type, contact_details
) VALUES (
    user_exists, "email", emailid
);
```

(or something similar, based on your exact table structure.)

Comment: Oh i got it , silly mistake on my part .. yep i forgot to put user_id into contact ..

Comment: Always glad to help :) If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily. :D